# Can "a long time" be an adverb meaning "for a long time"?

Tags: word-usage

See this real-world conversation:

> A: Something big going on in there?
>
> B: I couldn't say.
>
> A: You were in there **a long time**.

I would say "**a long time**" in the 3rd sentence is a noun & acts as an adverb.

I could see "**a long time**" adverb in the dictionary.

We got "**awhile**" (adverb) meaning "**for a while**" [Source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/awhile)

But we don't have "**alongtime**" adverb in dictionaries, although we have "**longtime**" adjective

a lot of noun can act as adverbs

> Yesterday was great
>
> I saw her yesterday

So, Can "**a long time**" be an adverb meaning "**for a long time**"?

Answer (score 1):

**A: You were in there  a long time**

Sometimes **groups of words** can act as the functioning parts of a sentence.  We call these pieces or chunks of language constituents.

The constituents in your sentence (A) include the following parts:

**Subject**= You

**Verb**= were

**in there**= a prepositional phrase working as an **adverb**  (adverbial) to say **where** you were.

**a long time**= a phrase acting as an **adverb**  (adverbial) to express a length of time (although the specific time isn't mentioned).

Therefore, it is true to say that **a long time** or **for a long time** are phrases that **function** as adverbs.

Answer (score 1):

*You were in there [a long time].*

You’re conflating parts of speech with function. The constituent “a long time” is a noun phrase consisting of three separate words whose parts of speech are determinative-adjective-noun. Together the noun phrase functions as an ‘adjunct’, more specifically a ‘durational adjunct’, since it describes the duration of your being in there as ‘long’.

The preposition “for” could optionally be inserted, which would convert the noun phrase into a preposition phrase, though the meaning and function would remain unchanged.

Note that the term ‘adjunct’ is preferable to the term ‘adverbial’.